# How should be the data for a SimpleExpandableListAdapter organized

Tags: android

I am trying to create a `ExpandableListView` with the `SimpleExpandableListAdapter`(I know I can extend a new adapter myself, but I want to try the simpleExapndableListAdapter).

Now I meet problems when I try to create a new instance of `SimpleExpandableListAdapter`.

Event I read the [references](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleExpandableListAdapter.html#SimpleExpandableListAdapter%28android.content.Context,%20java.util.List%3C?%20extends%20java.util.Map%3Cjava.lang.String,%20?%3E%3E,%20int,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20int%5B%5D,%20java.util.List%3C?%20extends%20java.util.List%3C?%20extends%20java.util.Map%3Cjava.lang.String,%20?%3E%3E%3E,%20int,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20int%5B%5D%29), I am not exactly sure what does the parameters mean especially the `groupData` and the `childData`.

Though I know I have to create a list of `Map` and a list of `list of Map`, but what data should be put there? How to organized them?

For example, this is the data I want to display, how to organize them?

```
++Development Team
  John
  Bill
++Data Process Team
  Alice
  David
```

BTW, does it mean that I have to create two layout for the group and the child view?

I have googled and read the tutorial again and again, but I can not understand it.

I hope someone can give ma an explain.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is simple sample you wanted, it will clear all your doubts..

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import android.app.ExpandableListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.SimpleExpandableListAdapter;

public class SimpleExpandableListExampleActivity extends ExpandableListActivity {
    private static final String NAME = "NAME";

    private ExpandableListAdapter mAdapter;

    private String group[] = {"Development" , "Data Process Team"};
    private String[][] child = { { "John", "Bill" }, { "Alice", "David" } };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        List<Map<String, String>> groupData = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
        List<List<Map<String, String>>> childData = new ArrayList<List<Map<String, String>>>();
        for (int i = 0; i < group.length; i++) {
            Map<String, String> curGroupMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
            groupData.add(curGroupMap);
            curGroupMap.put(NAME, group[i]);

            List<Map<String, String>> children = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
            for (int j = 0; j < child[i].length; j++) {
                Map<String, String> curChildMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
                children.add(curChildMap);
                curChildMap.put(NAME, child[i][j]);
            }
            childData.add(children);
        }

        // Set up our adapter
        mAdapter = new SimpleExpandableListAdapter(this, groupData,
                android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,
                new String[] { NAME }, new int[] { android.R.id.text1 },
                childData, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_2,
                new String[] { NAME }, new int[] { android.R.id.text1 });
        setListAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

}
```

All you have to do is

- Create an Android project with `SimpleExpandableListExampleActivity` as
  your main activity..
- Copy-paste the code given in that activity.
- Thats it.. Run your code...

Hope this helps...

Comment: It works. But I wonder how do you know the key `NAME` and how do you know the ids `R.id.text1` and etc? BTW,I found that the indicator is not aligned with the text, is there any idea to adjust them? See this:http://i.imgur.com/aeznDf7.png

Comment: Have you noticed `android.R.` used.. that means I have used layout what Android provides, I have not created it... You can find what it is though, just **Press Ctrl + android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1** You will find presence of `TextView` named  text1 there... As far as alignment of indicator with text is concerned,,, are you testing on emulator??, if yes then what(I dont see here...), Check on real device...  Let me know if want to know something else.. :)

Answer (score 0):

There are literally so many examples for your requirement!

Anyway, you might want to look into this blog, if you already haven't.

http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/04/10/expandable-listview-in-android-using-simpleexpandablelistadapter-a-simple-example/

"does it mean that I have to create two layout for the group and the child view?"

OF course, yes! , I mean you can choose to not create layouts, but then again it's your choice and this has very less to do with ExpandableList

The GroupList ideally would contain a list of Teams line List = {"Development Team", "Data Process Team"} (This will predominantly used for display purpose only like calculating the height of the list etc.)

The ChildList ideally would contain a list of lists (Hashmap of Lists rather)

Hashmap> =

Development Team: 
  List = {"John", "Bill"} 
Data Process Team: 
  List = {"John", "Bill"}

Answer (score 0):

You will need two lists or arrays.

**Parent** (Dev. Team and Data Process team)

The parent list is regular one, you will have to add all the parents i.e. top level items.

**Childrean**

The main difference between parent and children list, is that children list is a list of lists.

So for example if you need the children of the parent you will do something like this

```
children.get(parentPosition)
```

And if you need an specific child

```
children.get(parentPosition).get(childPosition)
```

[Here](https://github.com/Axxiss/android-utils-boilerplate/blob/master/src/main/java/io/github/axxiss/android/aub/adapters/BoilerplateExpandableListAdapter.java) you can find an example using `BaseExpandableListAdapter`

Comment: `The parent list is regular one, you will have to add all the parents i.e. top level items`. I just wonder why list of map? Why not using list of string? For example: `groups=new ArrayList<String>();groups.add("group1")?`

Comment: If you extends `BaseExpandableListAdapter` you can use an `ArrayList` of whatever kind of object. I don't the reason why Android devs are using a `Map` on `SimpleExpandableListAdapter`

Comment: Should the first `children.get(parentPosition)` be `parent.get(parentPosition)`?

Comment: `children.get(parentPosition)` will return the children list of the parent at `parentPosition` So if you need the parent you will do `parentList.get(parentPosition)`