# How to compare and group an ArrayList Object

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I am trying to group an `ArrayList` of event into a list of dates but have no idea how to achieve it.

My goal is to load the grouped data into an `ExpandableListView` see image below.

I have a list of dates and a list of events too. So, I want to group the events objects into different days based on their date attributes.

[image: exlistview]

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert your data in the way `ExpandableListAdapter` wants them.

Android has `SimpleExpandableListAdapter` that can be used but this does not look even a little to the screen you provided. Just for reference [here is an Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18351551/944070) using such an adapter, so you get a point how it works.

If you want something exactly as the screen you provided you have to implement a [custom expandable listiview](https://www.google.gr/webhp?q=android%20custom%20expandablelistview%20example) with `ExpandableListAdapter` by extending `BaseExpandableAdapter`

In case the items under the dates does not expand-collapse by pressing then I strongly sugest to look for a [ListView with Section Headers](http://javatechig.com/android/listview-with-section-header-in-android) the implementations is much easier.